# How does FSharpx.Stm deal with conflicts?

Tags: f#, stm

Supose we have the following code:

```
let tv1 = newTVar 1
let tv2 = newTVar 2

let transaction = 
    stm {
        let! v1 = readTVar tv1
        let! v2 = readTVar tv2
        let newV1 = v1 + v2
        let newV2 = 2 * newV1
        do! writeTVar tv1 newV1
        do! writeTVar tv2 newV2
    }
```

...and two threads are executing the transaction and the reads/writes happen in the following order:

1. threadA readTVar1
2. threadA readTVar2
3. threadA writeTVar1
4. threadB readTVar1
5. threadB readTVar2
6. threadB writeTVar1
7. threadA writeTVar2
8. threadB writeTVar2 --> conflict!!!!

Considering the conflict at step 8 I see two possibilities to solve the problem?

Possibility1: the **whole** transaction is retried i.e. threadB does readTVar1, readTVar2, writeTVar1, writeTVar2 again

Possibility2: the threadB goes back to readTVar2 and retries **only** readTVar2 and writeTVar2

So how does the transaction retry happen?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it's thread-safe unless you pipe the workflow to `atomically`, in which case, it becomes more apparent that the entire transaction (i.e. workflow) is retried.

Comment: Of course. The transaction would be executed with atomically. If atomically is not called then the transaction is not executed.